# Catching a specific exception at specific location in Python

Tags: python, exception

Is there a way to specialize where can I catch an exception in Python?
I'm making a backend for a game, and I want to make sure that user requests have a limited time to execute, and they time out after a while.
When they time out, I send a TimeoutException.

My problem is that my backend framework allows custom code for user requests to run, which is not written by me, and any try...catch block in that will catch my TimeoutException.
I'd very much like if they would not catch it, only my framework would catch. This way we wouldn't need to make a special case for TimeoutException put into every custom code.

A barebones example:

```
def main():
   try:
      with time_limit(30): #this raises TimeoutException if the execution time reaches 30s
         my_function()
   except TimeoutException:
     print("timeout!")

   def my_function():
      try:
         do_something()
      except:
         #this eats my TimeoutException
         pass
```

I want my exception to handled in the main function, and not the inner my_function, whatever it's content is.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is a clean solution.

But by catching the `TimeoutException` and re-raising it inside `my_function`, you can separate it from all the other exceptions, and pass it along to main:

```py
def my_function():
   try:
      do_something()
   except TimeoutException as e:
      # Transfer TimeoutException along to main
      raise TimeoutException(e)
   except:
      print("Regular except here")
```

Calling `main()` then prints the timeout in the error handling line 6 as desired:

```
>>> main()
timeout!
```

Hope this solves your issue. If it doesn't, as far as I know, all you can do is refuse to execute player code if it contains a bare `except:`.

You could do this by parsing their code first, before execution and raising an error if they have either `except:` or `except TimeoutException` in their code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this would require my team to always include that extra exception check in every code.